# Problem with anova() comparison function - corruption of model not reading second column

Tags: r, anova

I have been running an anova() comparison in rstudio. The function has been working fine with no problems. However, it just stopped reading the data from the second model. I have two separate data frames, both were running the code. However, when I started changing variable names something got corrupted and the anova no longer works. Here is what my code looks like:

```
# Fit Model 1
model1 <- lm(log_Income2005 ~ Educ16plus, data = grade_income)

# Calculate and display the ANOVA results for Model 1
cat("\n\nModel 1 ANOVA Results: ------------------------------------------\n")
model1_result <- anova(model1)
model1_result
# Extract R-squared, F-statistic, and Residual standard error for Model 2
r_squared_model1 <- summary(model1)$r.squared
f_statistic_model1 <- summary(model1)$fstatistic[1]
residual_standard_error_model1 <- summary(model1)$sigma

# Display F-statistic and Residual standard error for Model 2
cat("F-Statistic for Model 1:", f_statistic_model1, "\n")
cat("Residual Standard Error for Model 1:", residual_standard_error_model1, "\n")
cat("R-Squared for Model 1:", r_squared_model1, "\n")

#############################################################

# Fit Model 2
model2 <- lm(log_Income2005 ~ Educ16, data = grade_income)

# Calculate and display the ANOVA results for Model 2
cat("\n\nModel 2 ANOVA Results: ------------------------------------------\n")
model2_result <- anova(model2)
model2_result

# Extract R-squared, F-statistic, and Residual standard error for Model 2
r_squared_model2 <- summary(model2)$r.squared
f_statistic_model2 <- summary(model2)$fstatistic[1]
residual_standard_error_model2 <- summary(model2)$sigma

# Display F-statistic and Residual standard error for Model 2
cat("F-Statistic for Model 2:", f_statistic_model2, "\n")
cat("Residual Standard Error for Model 2:", residual_standard_error_model2, "\n")
cat("R-Squared for Model 2:", r_squared_model2, "\n")

##############################################################

# Perform an ANOVA comparison and display the results
cat("\n\nANOVA Comparison of Model's 1 & 2: --------------------------------\n")
compare1_2_result <- anova(model1, model2)
compare1_2_result
```

model1 and model2 both run correctly and have the correct output, but when I go to make the comparison the output is incomplete. It looks like this:

```
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: log_Income2005 ~ Educ16plus
Model 2: log_Income2005 ~ Educ16
  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq F Pr(>F)
1   2582 2357.2                      
2   2582 2387.6  0   -30.399
```

As I mentioned earlier this was not always happening. It used to function perfectly.

I have seen two additional warnings pop up in an earlier block of code related to the data frame. These warnings are also new. They are:

`Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters:` Educ2``

and

`Warning: longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`

I have tried this block of code with a different data frame and get similar warnings all related to the second column of the data frame, both of which are categorical variables.

Your help would be greatly appreciated!

This is what I have tried: My first thought was that rStudio was corrupted so I cleared all caches, history, etc, and saved with everything cleared and then restarted. That did not fix the problem. I also tried renaming variables, creating a new column in the data frame to hold that data, renaming the csv file, starting a new session, starting a new project, running the code in the terminal instead of in markdown, and updating rstudio. I don't think the problem is the code. Something else is happening behind the scenes.

Thanks again for any thoughts.

Comment: Your models are not nested. The comparison is only valid for nested models.

Comment: Hello Roland. Thank you. I nested them as suggested and am still missing those values. 
Any other thoughts?
model1 <- lm(log_Income2005 ~ Educ16plus, data = grade_income)
model2 <- lm(log_Income2005 ~ Educ16, data = grade_income)

# Nest Model 1 inside Model 2
nested_model <- lm(log_Income2005 ~ Educ16 * Educ16plus, data = grade_income)
model1_result <- anova(model1)
model1_result
model2_result <- anova(model2)
model2_result
nested_model_result <- anova(nested_model)
nested_model_result

compare1_2_result <- anova(nested_model, model2)
compare1_2_result